# What size junction box is needed for four 6 AWG copper wires?

Tags: electrical

Can somebody tell me what size and type of J box do I need for 4 #6 AWG copper wire? Boxes will be located outside. Both will be just and access point since I have more that 360 degree bends. Wire will be continuous.

Comment: If there's no tapping going on you should be able to get away with a straight [conduit body](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-1-1-4-in-Rigid-Threaded-Conduit-Body-58412/100183604) of the proper type for your conduit type; no need for a junction box. Code says - "...between pull points, for example, conduit bodies and boxes."

Comment: What size conduit and where do they penetrate the box?

Comment: C condulet with gasket and weather proof compression connectors on pipe to condulet

Answer (score 2):

Any (exterior) type you like, with a volume of 20 cubic inches **or more.** 5 cubic inches per #6 wire.

Here's a calculator http://www.constructionmonkey.com/calculations/electrical/boxfill

You may find boxes  bit larger than the minimum make your life easier, or are needed to make reasonable connection to your conduit size, etc.

Look up "figure 8 coiling" before you install your wire - if you can't get enough people to have one standing by (each of) the middle box(es) while you pull it end-to end, pull from one box to the next and figure-8 coil the wire on the ground - then flip the coil over and pull the next segment (no tangles.)